# Galois Theory: Finding the discriminant of a polynomial

Tags: galois-theory

I am very confused on how to determine the coefficient of: $f(x)=x^3-s_1x^2+s_2x-s_3$. Artin is really proving me with too much abstraction, is there an easier way to be thinking about how to do this. I need to somehow get a relation between this polynomial and it expressed with its actual roots.

Comment: Are these to be treated as numerical values?

Comment: You know that $s_1$ is the sum of the roots, and $s_3$ is their product, right?

Comment: I have the discriminant for $f(x)$ now, do I do the same for $g(y)$ if $g(y)$ if found by taking $x=y+\frac{s_1}{3}$ and taking $f(y+\frac{s_1}{3})$.

Comment: If I read this comment right, you should get the same discriminant.

Comment: @Lubin, yes this is what I want to shoe, but how do I get the discriminant of the first polynomial $f(x)$.

Comment: It would depend on which definition of the discriminant you’re using.

Comment: sum of square difference of the roots

Comment: Product, you mean, of course. It might help if you also make use of the fact that the discriminant is the product of $F'(\rho)$, where $\rho$ runs through the roots. This equivalence is not hard to check.

Comment: (my last comment) You can use your formula, just multiply it all out, then start subtracting off monomials in the $s$’s, starting with $27s_3^2$, and it all comes together. It is a computational pain, though, but a good exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the roots $\alpha_1,\alpha_2, \alpha_3$, then you will have the equality

> $$ (x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)=x^3-s_1x^2+s_2x-s_3.$$

Now, work out the left hand side of the above equation and try to finish the problem.

Comment: Okay so the discriminant is, $(\alpha_1 - \alpha_2)^2(\alpha_1 -\alpha_3)^2(\alpha_2 -\alpha_3)^2$?